# How to output escaped characters?

Tags: ruby, linux, string, console, escaping

How I can pass from

```
a = "blog.posts.[activity]-It's-raining"
```

to

```
blog.posts.\[activity\]-It\'s-raining.md
```

That is `a` with escaped symbols? In general, the string `a` must be read in console (linux)

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with code you've written we expect the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem along with a description of the problem. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Comment: @theTinMan More minimal that just a line of code is very difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Shellwords.escape`:

```
require "shellwords"
a = "blog.posts.[activity]-It's-raining"
puts Shellwords.escape(a)
```

This results in:

```
$ ruby foo.rb
blog.posts.\[activity\]-It\'s-raining
```